# How to breakout chunks of HTML context from a file

Tags: php

My db provides a var `"$a['html_content']"`, and I would like to extract from the "html_content" var a max of 6 blocks of html codes that are divided by an html element and attribute "div style" where each blocks will get re-asigned to a new var `"$this->set('qtrContent', $cntChunks)"`.  I am getting an empty array for my html output, any help would be greatly appreciated.  See the PHP code below:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$text = $dom->loadHTML($a['cnt_content']);
$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');

$cntChunks = array();
$max = 5;
$i = 0;
foreach ($divs as $div) {
    foreach ($div->attributes as $attr) {
        if($i > $max) break;
        $i++;

        $name = $attr->nodeName;
        $value = $attr->nodeValue;
        $find[$i] = '<div '.$name.'="'. $value.'">';
        $rows[$i] = explode($find[$i], $text[$i]);

        $cntChunks[] = $rows;
    }       
}

$cntChunks = array_values($cntChunks);
echo $cntChunks.'<br />';

$this->set('qtrContent', $cntChunks);
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to store in `$text` and `$rows[]`?

Comment: <code>$text</code> provides the file which has the html codes.  Each sections of the html codes are divided by the div elements.  I need to break out each section of the html codes and store them in <code>$rows</code>.

Comment: Have a look at [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and related objects.  You can use `loadHTML` method and then parse it as required to get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

#### You should read up on data types in PHP to prevent some errors in your code

`loadHTML()` returns bool to indicate whether there was an error instead of a string.

```
$text = $dom->loadHTML($a['cnt_content']);
```

Should therefore be

```
$text = $a['cnt_content'];
$success = $dom->loadHTML($a['cnt_content']);
```

And you can then continue, checking `$success` to prevent unexpected results when accessing `$dom` later on.

---

Your generation of the result seems a bit odd:

```
$find[$i] = '<div '.$name.'="'. $value.'">';
$rows[$i] = explode($find[$i], $text[$i]);
```

Try to create a simple result first, to verify you got the correct information

```
$rows[$i] = '<div '.$name.'="'. $value.'">';
```

---

`array_values()` returns an array instead of a string, so you would have to do something like

```
var_dump($cntChunks);
```

to check your results so far.